# Sum of duplicate values in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I'm sure similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find quite what I need.

I have a program that outputs a 2D array like the one below:

```
arr = [[0.2, 3], [0.3, "End"], ...]
```

There may be more or less elements, but each is a 2-element array, where the first value is a float and the second can be a float or a string.

Both of those values may repeat. In each of those arrays, the second element takes on only a few possible values.

What I want to do is sum the first elements' value within the arrays that have the same value of the second element and output a similar array that does not have those duplicated values.

For example:

```
input = [[0.4, 1.5], [0.1, 1.5], [0.8, "End"], [0.05, "End"], [0.2, 3.5], [0.2, 3.5]] 

output = [[0.5, 1.5], [0.4, 3.5], [0.85, "End"]]
```

I'd appreciate if the output array was sorted by this second element (floats ascending, strings at the end), although it's not necessary.

EDIT: Thanks for both answers; I've decided to use the one by Chris, because the code was more comprehensible to me, although groupby seems like a function designed to solved this very problem, so I'll try to read up on that, too.

UPDATE: The values of floats were always positive, by nature of the task at hand, so I used negative values to stop the usage of any strings - now I have a few if statements that check for those "encoded" negative values and replace them with strings again just before they're printed out, so sorting is now easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to accumulate the sum of the first value in the list keyed by the second item.

To get the 'string' items at the end of the list, the sort key could be set to positive infinity, `float('inf')`, in the sort key .

```
input_ = [[0.4, 1.5], [0.1, 1.5], [0.8, "End"], [0.05, "End"], [0.2, 3.5], [0.2, 3.5]]

d = dict()

for pair in input_:
    d[pair[1]] = d.get(pair[1], 0) + pair[0]

L = []
for k, v in d.items():
    L.append([v,k])

L.sort(key=lambda x: x[1] if type(x[1]) == float else float('inf'))

print(L)
```

This prints:

```
[[0.5, 1.5], [0.4, 3.5], [0.8500000000000001, 'End']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
out = [[key, sum([elt[0]for elt in val])] for key, val in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda elt: elt[1])]
>>> [[0.5, 1.5], [0.8500000000000001, 'End'], [0.4, 3.5]]
```

**Explanation**:

1. Groupby the 2D list according to the 2nd element of each sublist using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and the `key` parameters. We define the lambda `key=lambda elt: elt[1]` to groupby on the 2nd element:

```
for key, val in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda elt: elt[1]):
    print(key, val)
# 1.5 <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000026AD1F6E160>
# End <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000026AD2104EF0>
# 3.5 <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000026AD1F6E160>
```

2. For each value of the group, compute the `sum` using the buildin function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
for key, val in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda elt: elt[1]):
    print(sum([elt[0]for elt in val]))
# 0.5
# 0.8500000000000001
# 0.4
```

3. Compute the desired output:

```
out = []
for key, val in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda elt: elt[1]):
    out.append([sum([elt[0]for elt in val]), key])
print(out)
# [[0.5, 1.5], [0.8500000000000001, 'End'], [0.4, 3.5]]
```

---

Then you said about sorting on the 2nd value but there are `strings` and `numbers`, it's quite a problem for the computer.  It can't make a choice between a number and a string. Objects must be comparable.